# How do I define an input using Angle Brackets?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-3

I know how to make an input in Ember using curly braces:

```
{{input type="text" value=userInput}}
```

How do I do this using Angle Brackets component syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Input @type="text" @value={{@parentVal}} />
or
<Input @type="text" @value={{this.localVal}} />
```

are the Angle Bracket equivalent to `{{input type="text" value=userInput}}`.

In versions early in 3.x series, you don't need the `@` or `this` in front of the value attribute. `@` means the argument comes from the parent context, like a parent component or controller, while `this.` refers to a property that belongs to that component itself.

Angle brackets syntax for inputs was proposed in [RFC 459](https://emberjs.github.io/rfcs/0459-angle-bracket-built-in-components.html) and released in [version 3.10](https://blog.emberjs.com/2019/05/21/ember-3-10-released.html). If you are trying to convert existing hbs to Angle Brackets, check out [the syntax conversion guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.11.0/reference/) and check for [codemods](https://github.com/ember-codemods/ember-angle-brackets-codemod).